# no module named pandas.io.data found

Tags: python, jupyter

```
import pandas.io.data as wb
df=wb.Datareader('AAPL','google','2022/01/01','2022/01/01')
df.head()
```

I am running this code on jupyter notebook but I am getting this `module not found error`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: The `pandas.io.data` module is moved to a separate package `(pandas-datareader)`

So, Install

```
pip install pandas-datareader
```

use

```
import pandas_datareader
```

Ultimately, this can work

```
from pandas_datareader import data
df=data.DataReader('AAPL','yahoo','2016/1/1','2017/1/1')
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

for anaconda it is here:
[anaconda / packages / pandas-datareader 0.10.0](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pandas-datareader)

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
```

in Anaconda prompt